Is it possible to implement single sign-on feature in the community edition of strapi?
Is it possible to implement single sign on feature using google oauth in strapi community edition.
I saw that their documentation mentions that it is available only in Enterprise edition with gold plan.
However I want to check if there are any alternative ways by which I can implement this feature.

SSO is a feature exclusively available for Enterprise Edition and custom Strapi Cloud plans.
